# GC Configuration Details for mentioned opts file

Tags: garbage-collection

Can anyone please explain below (how it works)

```
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -
XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -
XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -
XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -
XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

Comment: Hi Phaniharam, welcome to StackOverflow. :) I think your question would get more answers (and upvotes) if you clarified it. What do you mean "how it works"? What exactly are you not sure about? And please remember: If any of the answers were helpful, upvote them, and if one fixed your problem, accept it (once you have enough reputation).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by 'how it works'.  Let's break it down:

PermSize=256m means you're using an older version of the JVM that still has a separate permanent generation (used to hold objects used by the JVM like Class objects).  Typically, this is 64Mb so this size would indicate you're loading a lot of classes.  This is the initial size.

MaxPermSize=256m means the permanent generation will be set to 256Mb and not resized as the application runs.

UseConMarkSweepGC means you are using the concurrent mark sweep algorithm (CMS).  Again, this is older and anything from JDK 8 would typically use the G1 collector instead. This is designed for lower latency, as opposed to the parallel collector (the default for older server class JVMs), which is for throughput.

CMSParallelRemarkEnabled.  CMS is mostly concurrent but not fully. After the initial, concurrent marking phase, the collector will pause all application threads and perform a remark to catch up on what changed during the initial mark.  This flag makes it use multiple threads rather than one.

CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70. When the old gen gets to 70% full the CMS collector starts working. The idea is to have the collector start late enough not to affect application performance (by running too frequently) but early enough not to run out of space.

UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly: Only use the percentage of the old gen that is full (occupancy fraction) to determine when the collector starts (avoids other GC heuristics).

ScavengeBeforeFullGC: Do a young generation GC prior to a full GC.

PrintGCDetails: Print details of GC activity.  More detail than just PrintGC will generate.

PrintGCDateStamps: Obviously print timestamps for when GC activities occur

PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime: Tells you how long the application threads were stopped by the GC

PrintPromotionFailure: This prints details of when objects fail to get promoted from the young to the old gen. This is often an indication of excessive fragmentation in the old gen, which requires a full compacting GC.

PrintHeapAtGC: This prints a lot of detail about what's in your heap when the GC runs. It really needs a tool to be of any use.

PrintTenuringDistribution: Prints details about how objects age (tenuring). This can be useful when deciding to change the tenuring threshold, which is how many times an object gets copied between survivor spaces before being tenured to the old gen.

Comment: What about -XX:+UseParNewGC mentioned above

Comment: Sorry, missed that one.

UseParNewGC simply means use the parallel collector (multi-threaded) for the young gen collections (i.e. minor ones).  There is obviously also a serial new collector.